# While editing the Spinner getting same Item Two times

Tags: android, android-spinner, editing

I am loading the **spinner** two times

1. For while inserting details
2. For editing the same details

When open the screen for editing spinner is to load the spinner with the selected Item which is selected while inserting the details.

now I what I have declared the Array List globally for loading the spinner. And at the same time I am assigning the item of selected while inserting.

now the data 
Code:
 **For loading the spinner** 
"Simple Loading wihile Inesertion"

```
 for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) 
                     {  
                         namesObject = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
                        valuesListForCtg.add(new MatchIDByString("-- Select Grievance Category --",-1));
                         for(int j=0; j<namesObject.getPropertyCount(); j++)
                         {
                            Object objectNames=namesObject.getProperty(j);
                            SoapObject soapObjectw = (SoapObject)objectNames;         
                            valuesListForCtg.add(new MatchIDByString(soapObjectw.getProperty("Category_Name").toString(),Integer.parseInt(soapObjectw.getProperty("Cat_ID").toString())));                                           
                         }

                     }
```

**The same spinner code above id Loading while editing  and the addition code for assigning the item as below**

```
valuesListForCtg.add(new MatchIDByString(namesObject.getProperty("Category_Name").toString(),Integer.parseInt(namesObject.getProperty("CategoryId").toString())));
```

Now the problem I am facing is the edited spinner is loading the selected item as well as assigned item.

**Code of Spinner**

```
SpnCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                try
                {

                MatchIDByString s = (MatchIDByString) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                CategoryValue = String.valueOf(s.StringID);                    
                CtgName = s.StringItem;
                IDStatusCtg = Integer.parseInt(CategoryValue);                  
                SpnForEditCtg = SpnCategory.getSelectedItemPosition();


                if(CategoryValue.equals("-1"))
                {
                    SpnCategoryType.setEnabled(false);
                    SpnCategoryType.setAdapter(null);
                }else
                {
                if (!CategoryValue.equals("0")) {
                    final boolean chk = isOnline();
                    if (chk != true) {              
                        PUC.InternetServiceNotAvailbale();              
                    }
                    else {
                        SpnCategoryType.setEnabled(true);
                    new LoadCategoryTypeSpinner().execute();
                    }
                }
                }

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    PUC.PleaseTryAgain();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are editing your details either create a new ArrayList or clear previous ArrayList before adding data into it. Otherwise it will add new data but it won't flush the previous data.

For better understanding you can post few more codes.

Comment: If I clear the array List then the data Which I want to Load for spinner get vanish. then How to set the selected Item for spinner which I want to set. And the above code Only I am using for Loading spinner

Comment: Now What I am getting is the Item Which I want to set as selected Item And Loading the data it also contains the same Item. So I am getting the 2 same items at same spinner

Comment: You are not clear. If you want to show just selected item then add a flag and if that item is selected then only add to the ArrayList.

Comment: You won't find exact code. But you can post your code so that we can check what you doing wrong.